# How to calculate the root of a project from a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm making a Ruby gem and want to calculate the directory root of the project the gem is included in. It's like `Rails.root`. How do I do that?

Whoever marked it as a duplicate question didn't link to a right question. None of those methods work - I tried them all. See my comments for an explanation too.

Comment: Without knowing what the project is, it's impossible to answer that question.

Comment: I think it'll be a project on Ruby. And Dir.getwd should work.

Comment: `Dir.getwd` is the directory the user was in when he started the whatever-the-project-is. It is completely unrelated to the project root.

Comment: It's just some random Ruby project. So you have a directory, /myproject, with a Gemfile in it. The Gemfile includes my gem. I want to be able to have a path to /myproject.

Comment: It should really be possible to downvote these dup-trolls -.- 

Answering is blocked so I give you an example how I do it. My gems are mostly for company internal use, but I guess it is acceptable for public gems as well.

module MyGem
  class << self
    attr_writer :project_path

    def project_path
      @project_path ||= begin
        fail "Please set project_path for #{self}" unless Bundler
        Bundler.root
      end
    end

    # For example
    def template_dir
      File.join(project_path, 'templates')
    end
  end
end

Comment: With Linebreaks:

module MyGem\n  class << self\n    attr_writer :project_path\n    def project_path\n      @project_path ||= begin\n        fail "Please set project_path for #{self}" unless defined? Bundler\n        Bundler.root\n      end\n    end\n    \n    # For example\n    def template_dir\n      File.join(project_path, 'templates')\n    end\n  end\nend\n

Answer (score -2):

`Dir.getwd`. This Ruby-method returns the path to the current working directory of this process as a string.